# What is the difference between GridSearch metrics and the normal metrics in sci-kit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have created a GradientBoostingClassifier and my objective was to get an AUC score of about .7.

When I run my code it returns this:

```
Grid best score (accuracy):  0.825
Accuracy: 0.326530612245

Grid best score (AUC):  0.695737012987
Test set AUC:  0.709330143541
```

Here is my code that prints this:

```
print('Test set AUC: ', roc_auc_score(y_test, y_decision_fn_scores_auc))
print('Grid best parameter (max. AUC): ', grid_clf_auc.best_params_)
print('Grid best score (AUC): ', grid_clf_auc.best_score_)
print('Accuracy:', clf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Can someone tell me what is the difference between these two scores and what I should be looking for?

Comment: Please read a tutorial on grid-search and tuning hyperparameters, esp. for classification; asking for tutorial recommendations is offtopic on SO. Your question *'what I should be looking for'* is also [way too non-specific and open-ended for SO rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also you didn't even say *which hyperparameter you're tuning* on your GBC; I'm guessing it's learning_rate but it could be several other things. And the sister site [DataScience.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) is more on-topic for this.

Comment: I didn't want to tune anything I just wanted to know the difference between the two.

Comment: If you didn't want to tune anything you wouldn't run grid-search (`GridSearchCV`) in the first place. Please read [any tutorial on what grid-search is and what it does](https://python-data-science.readthedocs.io/en/latest/evaluation.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By printing out `grid_clf_auc.best_score_`, you'll be getting the mean score (the score of the underlying classifier is used) of the best estimator resulting from the grid search, i.e. `best_estimator_.score`. In other words, how the best model resulting from the grid search performs on average on the validation sets when cross validating with the training data.

Whereas running `roc_auc_score(y_test, y_decision_fn_scores_auc))` on your test set, that is just giving you the score on "unseen" data, your test data, i.e. the final score that you should be regarding as a reference score of your model.